# MVVM Locator class in silverlight class libraries

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I'm experimenting with the MVVM pattern, specifically I am trying to determine how I'm going to work with separate class libraries that contain the views (and view models). Looking on the net it looks like this is being done in different ways with both prism and MEF, and it might be that is what I will end up doing.  Initially however, I'm working with the ServiceLocator sample that [John Papa created](http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/simple-viewmodel-locator-for-mvvm-the-patients-have-left-the-asylum) .

In that sample, the location of the ViewModelLocator is defined in app.xaml as a static resource:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:MVVMLib="clr-namespace:MVVMLib;assembly=MVVMLib" 
    x:Class="VMLocatorDemo.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <MVVMLib:ViewModelLocator x:Key="VMLocator"/>
        <MVVMLib:IndexerConverter x:Key="VMIndexerConverter" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and because view.xaml is in the same project, it can refer to the locator and everything is fine:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" 
      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMLocator}, Converter={StaticResource VMIndexerConverter}, ConverterParameter=MainPageViewModel}">        
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CompanyName}"/>
</Grid>
```

However, with separate class libraries, I can't do this because view.xaml doesn't know where the locator is, um, located.  I need the definition to remain in xaml so that I can continue to work with the different runtime/design time view models.

I guess my question is, how do I define the Locator class in the class library, or, is this precisely why other tools such as MEF and/or prism are required?

Many thanks

Jason

Answer (score 0):

Here is one using behaviors, and uses convention by default to find a view. We have service locator, but I guess it could be improved to not have dependency on this static class

```
public class ViewModelLocatingBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
    {
      #region Overrides

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            var viewType = AssociatedObject.GetType();

            var viewName = viewType.Name;
            var viewModelName = viewName.EndsWith("View")
                                    ? viewName + "Model"
                                    : viewName + "ViewModel";

         AssociatedObject.DataContext = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<object>(viewModelName);
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

in XAML

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <u:ViewModelLocatingBehavior/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not overly familiar with behaviours (new to Silverlight), but I've had a quick look and and I can see how it works. Is this typically how behaviours might be used, or is this just a creative way that you came up with to resolve a similar problem?  Are there any limitations or issues that I need to be aware of by doing it this way?